# AS3 - math.pow and math.log

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, math, logging, pow

I got following Math problem.

```
var a = Math.pow(b, c);
```

I got `a` and `c`. How can I get `b`? My math skilled withered over time.

Comment: Are you trying to find a number, where that number is raised to `c`, that equals `b`?

Answer (score 3):

var b = Math.pow(a, 1/c));

This is assuming you do not need to handle negatives.

Comment: This will not get you all the possible solutions, though. For example, both `2 ^ 2 = 4` and `(-2) ^ 2 = 4`, but using the above you get only 2 as the answer.